# Could not parse the remainder: '+1' from 'i+1' Error during template rendering

Tags: python, django

I'm new in python and here I need to increase the {{i}} with 1, so it would like this: `2017-2018` instead of `2017-2017+1`. I share my code bellow, pls help me out!! thanks in advance.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from mainapp.models import query
import datetime

def index(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    cdt = now.year
    if cdt:
        cdt = range(2017, int(cdt))
    return render(request,"mainapp/base.html",{'yy':cdt})
```

base.html

```
<html>
<head><title>{% block title %}AmeyaKrishi Version 2{% endblock %}</title></head>
<body>
    <h2>AmeyaKrishi V2 (testing mode): All University Filter</h2><hr>

    <p>     
        <form action="getFarmer" method="post">
        <select class="form-control" name="season">
            <option value="0">-- Select Year --</option>
            <option value="333">All Data</option>
            {% for i in yy %}
                <option value="{{i}}">{{i}} - {{i}}+1</option>
            {% endfor %}            
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Search >>">
        </form>
    </p>

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}  
</body>
</html>
```

BROWSER OUTPUT: (on local server)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD1c8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `add` built in template tag

```
<option value="{{i}}">{{i}} - {{i|add:"1"}}</option>
```

Comment: thank you so much @shafik .. one more request, could you please share a link where I could find the instructions to handle python html variables ??